# can I import css files in React.lazy?

Tags: css, reactjs, performance, import, lazy-loading

I am using lazy-loading libary to import my components to App.js component,
can I use, as well, lazy-loading to import my css files?

import component:

```
    const Lesson = React.lazy(() => import("./components/user/lesson/Lesson"));
```

any way to import like that the css files?

Anyway,
My project uses several css libraries,
Does it interfere with performance? Is it difficult to upload the site?
How to load css files efficiently?

I would be happy for any help!